# Grouping a grouped list of str without duplicates

Tags: python, list, optimization, duplicates

I have a grouped list of strings that sort of looks like this, the lists inside of these groups will always contain 5 elements:

```
text_list = [['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee'],
['fff','ggg','hhh','iii','jjj'],
['xxx','mmm','ccc','bbb','aaa'],
['fff','xxx','aaa','bbb','ddd'],
['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee'],
['fff','xxx','aaa','ddd','eee'],
['iii','xxx','ggg','jjj','aaa']]
```

The objective is simple, group all of the list that is similar by the first 3 elements that is then compared against all of the elements inside of the other groups.

So from the above example the output might look like this (output is the index of the list):

```
[[0,2,4],[3,5]]
```

Notice how if there is another list that contains the same elements but in a different order is removed.

I've written the following code to extract the groups but they would return duplicates and I am unsure how to proceed. I also think this might not be the most efficient way to do the extraction as the real list can contain upwards to millions of groups:

```
grouped_list = []
for i in range(0,len(text_list)):
    int_temp = []
    for m in range(0,len(text_list)):
        if i == m:
            continue
        bool_check = all( x in text_list[m] for x in text_list[i][0:3])
        
        if bool_check:
            if len(int_temp) == 0:
                int_temp.append(i)
                int_temp.append(m)
                continue
            int_temp.append(m)
           
    
    grouped_list.append(int_temp)
    
## remove index with no groups
grouped_list = [x for x in grouped_list if x != []]
```

Is there a better way to go about this? How do I remove the duplicate group afterwards? Thank you.

Edit:

To be clearer, I would like to retrieve the lists that is similar to each other but only using the first 3 elements of the other lists. For example, using the first 3 elements from list A, check if list B,C,D... contains all 3 of the elements from list A. Repeat for the entire list then remove any list that contains duplicate elements.

Comment: Can you please be clearer about the meaning of the statement: "group all of the list that is similar by the first 3 elements that is then compared against all of the elements inside of the other groups"?

Comment: Apart making the question clearer, please, check if changing `grouped_list.append(int_temp)` to `if not sorted(int_temp) in grouped_list and len(int_temp) > 0: grouped_list.append(sorted(int_temp))` does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, iGian. I added an explanation. Your suggestion also did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a set of frozensets to keep track of indices of groups with the first 3 items being a subset of the rest of the members:

```
groups = set()
sets = list(map(set, text_list))
for i, lst in enumerate(text_list):
    groups.add(frozenset((i, *(j for j, s in enumerate(sets) if set(lst[:3]) <= s))))
print([sorted(group) for group in groups if len(group) > 1])
```

If the input list is long, it would be faster to create a set of frozensets of the first 3 items of all sub-lists and use the set to filter all combinations of 3 items from each sub-list, so that the time complexity is essentially linear to the input list rather than quadratic despite the overhead in generating combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations

sets = {frozenset(lst[:3]) for lst in text_list}
groups = {}
for i, lst in enumerate(text_list):
    for c in map(frozenset, combinations(lst, 3)):
        if c in sets:
            groups.setdefault(c, []).append(i)
print([sorted(group) for group in groups.values() if len(group) > 1])
```

Comment: I ran your code but it returned ```[[0, 4], [3, 5]]``` instead of the desired output ```[[0,2,4],[3,5]]```

Comment: That's because your expected output is incorrect. The first 3 items of the sub-list at index 2 (`'xxx','mmm','ccc'`) is different from those at indices 0 and 4 (`'aaa','bbb','ccc'`).

Comment: Ah, I apologize. I might have worded the question wrongly. The first 3 items are used to compare against all of the elements inside the other sub-lists.

Comment: I always forget about https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault, good reminder for me.

Comment: @alD I see. I've updated the answer accordingly then.

Comment: Thanks blhsing, that worked. Much faster than my code. Although, it takes around 61 sec to compute for a list of size 13.9k. Other than using multiple cores, is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that's more efficient for longer input lists then.

Comment: Wow the speed difference is massive!! But the output from the 2 solutions are different.. The second solution returned a few elements less than the first one.  I'm unsure what went wrong

Comment: Can you update your question with a simplified/minimized version of your input that would reproduce the different outputs from the two solutions? You can simplify the input by retaining just the sub-lists that are referenced by the "missing elements" that are in the output of the first solution but not the second.